# Resolving Ambiguos columns without Ailas

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, aliases

I have a Dynamic query where the select columns are dynamically prepared. As this is a common code and I have some specific column choices, I have to put Aliases according to my query.
For this I had to use string replace.

I want to know if there is a provision in SQL Server to resolve the ambiguous columns without Alias.

i.e. Something like take values always from Table1 when there is ambiguity.

```
DECLARE @ColumnNames VARCHAR(1000)                                        
DECLARE @SQLStmt VARCHAR(MAX)
```

--Below I am getting list of column names comma separated 'Id,Name,Salary'....

```
SELECT @ColumnNames = testDB.dbo.testfuncion(45)

SET  @SQLStmt =   'SELECT '+@ColumnNames+' FROM Table1 LEFT Join Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID'
```

Name exists in both the tables, but lets say table two has less matching records. So I always want to get Name from Table1.

In anyway can we set a preference on one particular table using any inbuilt clause.

Comment: The query is unclear. You don't need to use any kind of string replacement to execute a query - that's a sure way to introduce conversion or SQL Injection vulnerabilities. Aliasing is already available with the `AS someOtherName` keyword. It looks like the *code* that generates the query is failing. Why don't you just use an ORM that supports LINQ, like EF?

Comment: No, there's no automatism... As your query is generated dynamically, you might either use a general alias with the table's name (e.g. `AS Table1_Name`), or you could use `Table1.*` and add all columns of `Table2`, where you do not find their name in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='Table1'`

Comment: `table two has less matching records` => This statement doesn't mean anything. Matching records will be common in both tables. Do you mean count of the tables?

Comment: Sorry, there is no feature that will automatically prefer one column over another with the same name.

Comment: What is this function doing: `testDB.dbo.testfuncion(45)`? What is the `45`?  I'm quite sure, that there is a better solution for your issue. Read about the [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: The code that *generates* the column list probably knows or *should* know the table names already. I would try to avoid such code at all costs though, both for security and performance reasons. For starters, why not use a *View*? Or an ORM on the client side? *This* code will result in different execution plans each time it's executed. It can't be optimized, indexed or secured, while a view can

Comment: parse the `@ColumnNames` to find out the columns name is in which table and add the prefix accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Simply prepend the columns with the true table name, like this:

```
SET @SQLStmt = 'SELECT Table1.'+REPLACE(@ColumnNames,',',',Table1.')+' FROM Table1 LEFT Join Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID'
```

This should turn your string of `Id,Name,Salary` into `Table1.Id,Table1.Name,Table1.Salary`

Comment: This will not be enough, if this select is used 1) as sub-select, 2) to create a view, 3) to create a TVF or 4) to be used in a CTE. In all these cases, the returned column names must be unique...

Comment: @Shnugo There was no mention of this in the OP, so I wasn't aware that it was an important factor.

Comment: You are right, this is not mentioned in the OP... I just wanted to point to the fact, that your suggestion will not be sufficient for many cases... But it might be a good answer though...

Comment: @Shnugo Fair enough. The question got updated anyway, so maybe my new edit will be enough. We shall see! XD